# How to install package in mobile devices through salesforce1 application or any other way

Tags: managed-package, salesforce1-app, mobile, appexchange, security-review

I have developed an application in a salesforce account. and I have created the package and can publish on the appexchange. Now, that uploaded application on the appexchange can be installed in another salesforce account through browser from appexchange.

We use salesforce1 in the mobile devices. I want to get know how can we install any package through salesforce1 which is published on appexchange in the mobile devices ?

Is there any other way ?

Update

Example:

There is an application developed by any organization from salesforce developer account. and that is published on the appexchange. Now, if we want to install that application into any other salesforce production/sandbox/developer account, **we go to appexchange website from the browser**, and do process further. and **that application will be used into another organization.**

In the web, We use browser to install the application into the another salesforce organization.

Now, if I want to use or install any salesforce application in salesforce mobile device that is developed by any organization. How can I install that through salesforce1 or any other way except browser ?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking if your app can be installed directly by a user on his cell phone as opposed to being installed by an Admin in the User's Org? If the latter, does the App access any of the data that's in the Org?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated my question.

Comment: @crmprogdev. My question is not who installed the app in the Org. but, Instead of using appexchange from the browser in the mobile device, do we have other way to install the app in the mobile device. I had to open the browser in the ipad, and install the app in the salesforce account through browser for testing purpose. later on, that installed app was visible in the salesforce1. but, Can we achieve from salesforce1 logging account ? or any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

Your last comments and your edited question don't seem congruent to me. The answer that follows is in response to your last comment which seems to me to be about installing an app to a device from an Org.

The only alternative that I know of at this time is to install an app to a device from within an org using [Private App Exchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4VlZEAV) which is like a mini App Exchange an Org can use to make "Org/Admin Approved" apps available to users for download to use on their devices. Presumably, an Admin could provide a link to a User from which to download an App to their device, but I have no experience with it to say whether or not that's the case or if one must use their browser to access/install an app.

I suggest you install the Private App Exchange in a Dev Org and test it with the apps you've created to see how well it works with them.

Comment: I will look at that. but, Private App Exchange would require to install into the organization from the browser in the mobile device ? then we can install other application from appexchange using that Private App Exchange into the salesforce organization.